# Not able to add duplicate records to json object

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement repeating events option to full calendar. I am storing only one instance of the event and its repeating details in db.

According to the repeating details i am trying to repeat the event from php code, which i am posted below.

```
       $calendar_query = "select * from test.calendar where User_Id = 07";
    $Calendar_res = mysql_query($calendar_query) or die(mysql_error());


    while ($calendar_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Calendar_res)) {
    $flag=false;
    $cal_id=$calendar_row['Calendar_Id'];
    $Repeating_query="select * from repeating_event where Calendar_id='$cal_id'";
    $Repeating_res = mysql_query($Repeating_query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($repeating_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Repeating_res)) {

    if($repeating_row['repeats']==0){
    $flag=true; $i=0;
    while($i<$repeating_row['ends_after']){
    if($i==0){

    $eventsArray['id'] =  $calendar_row['Calendar_Id'];
    $eventsArray['userid'] = $calendar_row['User_Id'];
    $eventsArray['title'] = $calendar_row['Event_Title'];
    $eventsArray['start'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($calendar_row['StartDateTime']));
    $eventsArray['end'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($calendar_row['EndDateTime']));
    $eventsArray['description'] = $calendar_row['Event_Desc'];
    $eventsArray['venue']=$calendar_row['Event_Venue'];
    $d1=strtotime($calendar_row['StartDateTime']);
    $d2=strtotime($calendar_row['EndDateTime']);
    if($d1==$d2){
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = true;
    }
    else{
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = false;
    }
    }   

    else{

    $eventsArray['id'] =  $calendar_row['Calendar_Id'];
    $eventsArray['userid'] = $calendar_row['User_Id'];
    $eventsArray['title'] = $calendar_row['Event_Title'];
    $eventsArray['start'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($calendar_row['StartDateTime']) + ($repeating_row['repeats_every']*86400));
    $eventsArray['end'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($calendar_row['EndDateTime']) + ($repeating_row['repeats_every']*86400));
    $eventsArray['description'] = $calendar_row['Event_Desc'];
    $eventsArray['venue']=$calendar_row['Event_Venue'];
    $d1=strtotime($calendar_row['StartDateTime']);
    $d2=strtotime($calendar_row['EndDateTime']);
    if($d1==$d2){
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = true;
    }
    else{
    $eventsArray['allDay'] = false;
    }
    }  
    $i++;
    }
    }
    }

$events[] = $eventsArray;

}

echo json_encode($events);
```

***Output is:***

```
[{"id":"20","userid":"7","title":"Suresh Birthday","start":1357686000,"end":1357686000,"description":"suresh birthday on 9t april","venue":"Bangalore","allDay":true},
{"id":"22","userid":"7","title":"appointment with doctor","start":"2012-12-01 01:00:00","end":"2012-12-01 02:00:00","description":"for dental checkup","venue":"fortis","allDay":false},
{"id":"23","userid":"7","title":"asdfasd","start":1363042800,"end":1363042800,"description":null,"venue":null,"allDay":true},
{"id":"70","userid":"7","title":"asdf","start":1358204400,"end":1358204400,"description":"asdf","venue":"asdf","allDay":true},
{"id":"71","userid":"7","title":"rahj","start":1358895600,"end":1358895600,"description":"","venue":"as","allDay":true},
{"id":"81","userid":"7","title":"cc","start":1356908400,"end":1356908400,"description":"cc","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"82","userid":"7","title":"kk","start":1358722800,"end":1358722800,"description":"","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"83","userid":"7","title":"mm","start":1359327600,"end":1359327600,"description":"","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"84","userid":"7","title":"vv","start":1359068400,"end":1359068400,"description":"","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"85","userid":"7","title":"zz","start":1358463600,"end":1358463600,"description":"zz","venue":"zz","allDay":true},
{"id":"87","userid":"7","title":"qq","start":1358118000,"end":1358118000,"description":"qq","venue":"qq","allDay":true}]
```

***Expected Result:-***

```
[{"id":"20","userid":"7","title":"Suresh Birthday","start":1357686000,"end":1357686000,"description":"suresh birthday on 9t april","venue":"Bangalore","allDay":true},
{"id":"22","userid":"7","title":"appointment with doctor","start":"2012-11-28 01:00:00","end":"2012-11-28 02:00:00","description":"for dental checkup","venue":"fortis","allDay":false},
{"id":"22","userid":"7","title":"appointment with doctor","start":"2012-11-29 01:00:00","end":"2012-11-29 02:00:00","description":"for dental checkup","venue":"fortis","allDay":false},
{"id":"22","userid":"7","title":"appointment with doctor","start":"2012-11-30 01:00:00","end":"2012-11-30 02:00:00","description":"for dental checkup","venue":"fortis","allDay":false},
{"id":"22","userid":"7","title":"appointment with doctor","start":"2012-12-01 01:00:00","end":"2012-12-01 02:00:00","description":"for dental checkup","venue":"fortis","allDay":false},
{"id":"22","userid":"7","title":"appointment with doctor","start":"2012-12-02 01:00:00","end":"2012-12-02 02:00:00","description":"for dental checkup","venue":"fortis","allDay":false},
{"id":"23","userid":"7","title":"asdfasd","start":1363042800,"end":1363042800,"description":null,"venue":null,"allDay":true},
{"id":"70","userid":"7","title":"asdf","start":1358204400,"end":1358204400,"description":"asdf","venue":"asdf","allDay":true},
{"id":"71","userid":"7","title":"rahj","start":1358895600,"end":1358895600,"description":"","venue":"as","allDay":true},
{"id":"81","userid":"7","title":"cc","start":1356908400,"end":1356908400,"description":"cc","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"82","userid":"7","title":"kk","start":1358722800,"end":1358722800,"description":"","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"83","userid":"7","title":"mm","start":1359327600,"end":1359327600,"description":"","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"84","userid":"7","title":"vv","start":1359068400,"end":1359068400,"description":"","venue":"","allDay":true},
{"id":"85","userid":"7","title":"zz","start":1358463600,"end":1358463600,"description":"zz","venue":"zz","allDay":true},
{"id":"87","userid":"7","title":"qq","start":1358118000,"end":1358118000,"description":"qq","venue":"qq","allDay":true}]
```

**You can clearly see in the expected i have 5 instances of "id": "22", but in output i am getting only one.**

The problem i am facing here is:- not able to save duplicate instances of the same event.

The loop structure seems alright to me, if i put echo statements in loop, its displaying 'n' occurrences as per repeating details, but if i am encoding it to json, final json object is only having latest record of the event(nothing but last repeated details of the event).

I am guessing json is not allowing duplicate records, I wanted it to have duplicate records, Please suggest me, where i am going wrong.. :-)

Comment: You might get more help if you took the time to format the code so that people don't have to scroll back and forth to read it. Basic courtesy: Make it easy to read your question and code. There's no need for a 40-some-odd indent.

Comment: Separately: I'm not much of a PHP guy, but I don't think JSON is your problem. But specifically re JSON: An object can have only one value for a property, but that value can be an array. That's how you put multiple values on a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are setting into `$events[]` several states of the same `$eventsArray`... why don't you reinitialize it at the beginning of each loop: `$eventsArray=array()`...?

Comment: Your code is hard to read w/o indent. I meant inside the loop just before you start assigning `$eventsArray`. This does not look like a json prob; do a `print_r($events)`...

Comment: what i did is i added `$events[] = $eventsArray;` in `if($repeating_row['repeats']==0){}`